# Trouble with Dynamic IPTables For Loop

Tags: bash, for-loop, iptables

I would greatly appreciate any feedback with this.  There is an initialize iptables bash script that allows everything my host needs; however, one of the endpoints that the host needs to talk to is a dns name, so periodically that rule needs to be adjusted.

Here is what the iptables output chain looks like before my script runs:

```
Chain OUTPUT (policy DROP)
num  target     prot opt source               destination
1    ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             6.6.6.6        tcp dpt:https state NEW,ESTABLISHED /* Google */
2    ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             7.7.7.7        tcp dpt:https state NEW,ESTABLISHED /* Google */
3    ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             dns.google           udp dpt:domain state NEW,ESTABLISHED /* DNS1 UDP OUT */
4    ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             dns.google           udp dpt:domain state NEW,ESTABLISHED /* DNS2 UDP OUT */
5    ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
6    ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp spt:7070 ctstate ESTABLISHED /* Connection to AWS */
7    ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp spt:http ctstate ESTABLISHED
8    ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp spt:ssh ctstate ESTABLISHED
9    ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere
10   ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:ntp
11   DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

I wrote a script so I can update the google ip address in iptables.  When the script is ran manually I can't duplicate the problem.  When the script is ran as root via crontab (every 10 minutes), after a few hours or so, some of the other iptables rules are being removed.

```
#!/bin/bash
PATH=/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin

hostname="google.com"

if [[ $EUID -ne 0 ]]; then
   echo "This script must be ran as root"
   exit 1
fi

new_ip=$(/bin/dig +short $hostname| head -n2)
old_ip=$(/usr/sbin/iptables --line-number -nL OUTPUT | grep Google | cut -f26 -d ' ')


if [ "$new_ip" = "$old_ip" ] ; then
    echo "IP address has not changed"
else
    echo "IP address has been changed"
    echo "Updating IPTables now"
    deleterule=$(/usr/sbin/iptables --line-number -nL OUTPUT | grep Google | cut -f1 -d ' ' | sort -nr)
    for rules in $deleterule
    do
        /usr/sbin/iptables -D OUTPUT "$rules"
    done
    for ip in $new_ip
    do
        /usr/sbin/iptables -I OUTPUT -p tcp -d "$ip" --dport 443 -m comment --comment "Google" -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
    done
fi
```

Again this script works fine if I run it manually and it'll work for a little while running as a crontab, but when it starts deleting other rules, it creates a problem.

Here is what iptables looks like after a day of running as a crontab:

```
Chain OUTPUT (policy DROP)
num  target     prot opt source               destination
1    ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
2    ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp spt:7070 ctstate ESTABLISHED /* Connection to AWS */
3    ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp spt:http ctstate ESTABLISHED
4    ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp spt:ssh ctstate ESTABLISHED
5    ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere
6    ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:ntp
7    DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

As you can see, it's removing entries that it doesn't need to

Comment: Btw.: By convention, I would use lowercase variable names. HOSTNAME is a usually preassigned variable.

Comment: Also paste your script at https://shellcheck.net for syntax validation.

Comment: I've changed everything to lowercase.  I've done the spellcheck (no error)

Comment: Your regexes look really relaxed. Without examples of the lines they are supposed to match, it's hard to propose improvements. Perhaps a better approach altogether would be to have a bunch of files with rules, and then when you update one of them, run a script which combines them and replaces the currently active rules.

Comment: This might help: [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/74329)

Comment: @tripleee let me update the post.  1 second

Comment: [BashFAQ #1](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) and [DontReadLinesWithFor](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor) are also worth reading. `anything=$(foo); for line in $anything` is an antipattern; `while read -r firstcol secondcol rest; do ...; done < <(foo)` avoids needing to store `foo`'s output in RAM, but more importantly avoids bugs related to string-splitting/globbing/etc.

Comment: Also, consider replacing `grep Google | cut -f1` with `awk '/Google/ { print $1 }'`. One _could_ also do the sort operation internal to awk, but that's more work.

Comment: BTW, consider temporarily deleting your post and undeleting it when you're done editing if you don't want new comments/votes/etc while you're working on improving it. If if it's closed or deleted by vote it takes another vote (or an elected moderator) to reopen/undelete, if you delete it yourself you can undelete whenever you like.

Comment: With respect to a script behaving differently from cron -- most reliable place to start is logging. `set -x` to enable trace logging, `exec 2>/path/to/logfile` to store that trace somewhere, and maybe add `tee` to your pipelines if that'd help (`iptables --line-number -nL OUTPUT | tee /path/to/iptables-starting.$$ | grep ...`).